# auto decrementing row serial number while deletion

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I am using this code for row deleting in gridview. It should be like this "while it deleted a row, take row number 5 with serial no 5, serial field of row number 6 should become 5. means decrementing the serial number after one row deleted."   but it is not happening while I delete row no 5 with serial 5, the row number 6 remains the same.

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
        For Each control As Control In e.Row.Cells(0).Controls
            Dim DeleteButton As LinkButton = TryCast(control, LinkButton)
            If DeleteButton IsNot Nothing AndAlso DeleteButton.Text = "Delete" Then
                DeleteButton.OnClientClick = "return(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?'))"
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "Delete" Then
        ' get the categoryID of the clicked row

        Dim Serial As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
        ' Delete the record 
        Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM target WHERE SlNo = '" & Serial & "'", con)
        con.Open()
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        bindphoto2()
        Label1.Text = "File has been deleted succefully"
    End If
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDeleting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
    Dim Serial As Integer = CInt(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)
    Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM target WHERE SlNo = '" & Serial & "'", con)
    con.Open()
    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve by having serial number w/o any gaps? Maintaining such serial number means updating all later records for decrementing the serial - depending upon the size of record-set, it could be expensive operation. Most of the time, a calculated serial number (e.g. using ranking functions) or implied (by index within a ordered set) suffice.

Comment: +1. It DOES make sene for somete things though - running item numbers (Invoice, Invoice Item while editing an invoice) but you would NEVER use that as ID (tons of nasty side effects possible), only as a field.

Answer (score 0):

This might help :)

> Dim strRowNumber As String = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString()

```
   While strRowNumber.Length < dgvFilter.RowCount.ToString().Length
        strRowNumber = "0" & strRowNumber
    End While
```

> e.Graphics.DrawString(strRowNumber, Me.Font, b, e.RowBounds.Location.X + 15, e.RowBounds.Location.Y + ((e.RowBounds.Height - size.Height) / 2))
>   'Write this code on RowPostPaint event 
>   take care